# Ampscript block not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to fetch some user information from a survey page to a data extension. for this all things are at place and I am redirecting subscriber to a thank you page and capturing this information.

```
   %%[
var @q5_overallHow5, @q6_didOur6, @q8_wouldYou8, @q10_whatAspect10, @q11_whatAspect, @q12_pleaseExplain, @EmailAddress

set @q5_overallHow5 = RequestParameter('q5_overallHow5')
set @q6_didOur6 = RequestParameter('q6_didOur6')
set @q8_wouldYou8 = RequestParameter('q8_wouldYou8')
set @q10_whatAspect10 = RequestParameter('q10_whatAspect10')
set @q11_whatAspect = RequestParameter('q11_whatAspect')
set @q12_pleaseExplain = RequestParameter('q12_pleaseExplain')
set @EmailAddress = RequestParameter('EmailAddress')


InsertData("SurveyResults",
           "q5_overallHow5",@q5_overallHow5,
           "q6_didOur6",@q6_didOur6,
     "q8_wouldYou8",@q8_wouldYou8, 
     "q10_whatAspect10",@q10_whatAspect10, 
     "q11_whatAspect",@q11_whatAspect, 
     "q12_pleaseExplain",@q12_pleaseExplain, 
   "EmailAddress",@EmailAddress
   )
]%%
```

This code was working fine but now all of a sudden something's not working as expected and on submit button there is a 500 internal server error.

I have checked all the settings under cloud page and removing this ampscript is allowing me to save and publish the content but I am not able to save and publish after putting this ampscript block.

Please have a look on this [page](https://gist.github.com/pragyanshukukreti/a3ab933e88431cb23a3642e70bb80cf3)

Comment: Do you have a primary key on your SurveyResults Data Extension? Any Required/Not Nullable fields?

Comment: Have you always had those line breaks in the InsertData function?

Comment: yes, I believe so, I do have a primary key in my DE without it system won't let me save the data extension. "q5_overallHow5" is primary key. This DE is not sendable nor testing. rest of the feilds are set to nullable. Besides there is no required field in my survey form which I have created using HTML. that can be found here https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/wethzsthteg/gyu52oslskq

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You can create a Data Extension without a primary key, certainly. And are you trying to insert a value for "q5_overallHow5" that already exists in the table?

Comment: I have checked and figured out that after removing this inserdata function, page is saving and publishing fine. so I'm not sure what is wrong in this inserdata functio./

Comment: So, it's the publish step where you get the 500 error? Not where you actually try to view the page?

Answer (score 1):

@andrew it was just spinning when I was trying to publish this thank you page, after removing this insertdata function saving and publish were working fine. I created a new data extension will all nullable fields and right now it allowed me to save this thank you page.  and this works fine now. I/m not sure what was the issue with this Data extension but creating a new data extension with same fields resolved this issue.